# How to deploy Elasticsearch on Azure blob storage

Tags: azure, elasticsearch

To deploy elastic search i followed steps in "Azure Marketplace Elasticsearch offering youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6oRIpSXYrC4.

Then i copied kibana IP with port no 5601 and entered same credentials which i gave during this steps. But my credentials is not working. I am not sure either my credentials is wrong or is there any prerequisite before deploying elastic search on Azure.

If my credentials are wrong then how i can reset them?

Comment: Did you setup external load balancer during setup?

Comment: yes i choose external load balancer.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, the question not properly exposed, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit the question above. thanks